# How can I pass an option in a select tag to another select tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of options in a select tag, then an element to pass a selected option to others select tag. My 'select' is in multiple forms so each option is displayed as a line of text. What I want to achieve is after I click on an option, then click on the declare variable with 'onclick' function, that option will be pass to others select tag.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container row" style="display:flex;" id="employeeTransfer">
   <label class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 pb-sm-5 pb-5">Người nhận</label>
   <select id="employeeDisplay" class="col-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 form-control" multiple style="margin-left:12px;">
      <option id="1">Bùi Thị Bưởi</option>
      <option id="2">Tằm Thị Dâu</option>
      <option id="3">Cao Văn Bách</option>
   </select>
   <div class="col-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-sm-1 pb-sm-5 pb-5">
      <ul style="list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0; padding-top:40%; padding-left:30%;">
         <li id="sendEmployee" onclick="processEmployee()">⫸</li>
         <li id="returnEmployee">⫷</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <select id="employeeProcess" class="col-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 pb-sm-5 pb-5 form-control" multiple>
   </select>
</div>
<br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple task - just take the currently selected option from the first drop-down and create a new option in the second select:

```js
function processEmployee()
{
  var select_1 = document.getElementById('employeeDisplay');
  var select_2 = document.getElementById('employeeProcess');
  var option, i, j, found;

  for (i = 0; i < select_1.options.length; i++)
  {
    if (select_1.options[i].selected)
    {
      found = false;
      for (j = 0; j < select_2.options.length; j++)
      {
        if (select_2.options[j].value == select_1.options[i].value)
        {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(!found)
      {
        select_2.add(new Option(select_1.options[i].text,select_1.options[i].value));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why do we need to delete all select 2 option whenever I want to transfer another from my select 1? Also option.text failed to get the text. It can only pass the value. What worse is that whenever the first item of select 1 is always be converted to the last value of last item.

Comment: I updated the answer to not delete the existing options in the second SELECT.